# Function to trim leading and trailing whitespace in vba

Tags: regex, excel, vba, trim

I have checked quite a few suggestions re trimming leading & trailing whitespace in vba (excel, incidentally).

I have found this solution, but it also trims å ä ö (also caps) and I am too weak in regex to see why:

```
Function MultilineTrim (Byval TextData)
    Dim textRegExp
    Set textRegExp = new regexp
    textRegExp.Pattern = "\s{0,}(\S{1}[\s,\S]*\S{1})\s{0,}"
    textRegExp.Global = False
    textRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    textRegExp.Multiline = True

    If textRegExp.Test (TextData) Then
      MultilineTrim = textRegExp.Replace (TextData, "$1")
    Else
      MultilineTrim = ""
    End If
End Function
```

(this is from an answer here at SO, where the useraccount seems inactive:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606433/3701019
)

So, I would love if anyone could help with either (a) an alternative solution to the problem or (b) a version of the regexp / code that would not strip out (single) åäö characters.

Thanks for any help!

Details:
Problem

- Trim functions in vba do not consider all whitespace chars (tabs, for instance). Some custom trim is needed
- The best solution I found is above, but it also removes single å ä ö characters.

My context is a xmlparser in vba, where it gets chunks of xml to parse. It sometimes just gets a character from the stream, which may be å ä ö, which then this function strips away completely.

I would be happy to clarify or edit this question, of course.

***FYI: I have shared exactly what I did based on the answers, see below.***

Comment: Regex are probably not the right way to tackle this problem: they will work, but they are slow and you will end-up creating a new Regex object every time you call your `Trim()` function, which is probably a lot and will add lots of overhead if you use that function as you parse tokens from a text/xml file. I would go old-school on this and simple use old-fashioned string manipulation functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct, w r t instancing! But I see no need to instance the regex everytime. In adding this little snippet to my code, I put it in a class and reuse the regex and thus only create one instance. In general, the performance bottleneck of the (data retrieval) code is elsewhere.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to create a class if you are just using this as a normal helper functions. You can just use a `Static` declaration instead of a `Dim` for the regex inside the function itself and initialise it the first time it is used.

Comment: For an explanation of why I rolled back your second revision, please read [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262806/2359271)

Comment: OK, @Air, thanks. I read the post you mentioned, but I did not understand what it was trying to get me to do. So I [asked specifically](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298405/add-description-of-used-solution-how?noredirect=1#comment215724_298405) and got some other perspectives, so now I understand and added what I did below. Naturally, accepted answer still remains the same, although it does not capture exactly what I did, which I've tried to make clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a regex I would use:

```
^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$
```

This will match the "usual" whitespace characters as well as the NBSP, commonly found in HTML documents.

VBA Code would look something like below, where S is the line to Trim:

```
Dim RE as Object, ResultString as String
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RE.MultiLine = True
RE.Global = True
RE.Pattern = "^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$"
ResultString = RE.Replace(S, "")
```

And an explanation of the regex:

```
Trim whitespace at the start and the end of each line
-----------------------------------------------------

^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$

Options:  ^$ match at line breaks

Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^[\s\xA0]+»
   Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\s\xA0]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
      The character with position 0xA0 (160 decimal) in the character set «\xA0»
Or match this alternative (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «[\s\xA0]+$»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\s\xA0]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
      The character with position 0xA0 (160 decimal) in the character set «\xA0»
   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Tried this, and this seems to do the trick. Going to go with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function that strips out the characters that you don't want specifically.

```
Private Function CleanMyString(sInput As String) As String
   Dim sResult As String

   ' Remove leading ans trailing spaces
   sResult = Trim(sInput)
   'Remove other characters that you dont want
   sResult = Replace(sResult, chr(10), "")
   sResult = Replace(sResult, chr(13), "")
   sResult = Replace(sResult, chr(9), "")

End Function
```

This does not use regex though.  Not sure if thats OK for your requirements?

Comment: This wouldn't work as the `Replace()` would also remove whitespace characters that are _inside_ the string, not just at the edges of it. Additionally, there is no `char()` function, it's `Chr()` instead (or, slightly more efficient, `Chr$()`).

Comment: Another minor nitpick, but you can use `vbTab`, `vbCr`, `vbLf` constants instead of 9, 10, 13. It's also slightly more efficient to use `vbNullString` instead of an empty `""` string because that constant is already defined and the VBA engine doesn't have to reallocate a new empty string for each `""` it encounters, it will re-use the one defined by the constant instead. (the VBA engine isn't as smart as VB.Net in these optimisations).

Comment: Apologies.  Have fixed char to chr in the answer.  Thanks for the correction on the constants.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function MultilineTrim (Byval TextData)
    Dim textRegExp
    Set textRegExp = new regexp
    textRegExp.Pattern = "(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$)"
    textRegExp.Global = True
    textRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    textRegExp.Multiline = True

    MultilineTrim = textRegExp.Replace (TextData, "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - tried this and it seems to work except it leaves a crlf at the start (or atleast either cr or lf, a new line anyway).

Answer (score 1):

After [consulting with stackexchange people on how to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298405/add-description-of-used-solution-how), I am adding the edit of the question as my own answer, instead. Here it is:

## Answer / Used code

Thanks to the answer(s), this is what I will be using:

```
Function MultilineTrim(ByVal TextData)
    MultilineTrim = textRegExp.Replace(TextData, "")

'    If textRegExp.Test(TextData) Then
'        MultilineTrim = textRegExp.Replace(TextData, "$1")
'    Else
'        MultilineTrim = "" ' ??
'    End If
End Function

Private Sub InitRegExp()
    Set textRegExp = New RegExp
    'textRegExp.Pattern = "\s{0,}(\S{1}[\s,\S]*\S{1})\s{0,}" 'this removes å ä ö - bug!
    'textRegExp.Global = False

    'textRegExp.Pattern = "(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$)" ' leaves a line break at start
    textRegExp.Pattern = "^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$" ' works! Ron Rosenfelds submit

    textRegExp.Global = True

    textRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    textRegExp.MultiLine = True
End Sub
```

Thanks again all! (nod to Ron Rosenfeld)

Answer (score 1):

Refactored and improved Richard Vivians version

```
Function cleanMyString(sInput)
    ' Remove leading and trailing spaces
    sInput = Trim(sInput)
    'Remove other characters that you dont want
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(10), "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(13), "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(9), "")
    cleanMyString = sInput
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

I would call Trim after replacing all the other characters.  This way if there are spaces after the other characters they will also be removed.