# clean a Word document from multpile whitespace characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to clean each line of selected text in Word so that any not needed characters (tab, multiple spaces, multiple new line characters, empty lines) will be deleted.

Let's say I have a text:

```
John        Smith 



John    Anderson Smith  

John           A. Smith     
J.A. Smith
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
John Smith 
John Anderson Smith 
John A. Smith 
J.A. Smith
```

Let me show you what I have tried so far. Removing tabs is quite easy:

```
With Selection
    .Text = Replace(.Text, vbTab, "")
End With
```

The same goes for new line characters:

```
With Selection
    .Text = Replace(.Text, vbCrLf, ",")
End With
```

Unfortunately, it fails to work when I try to remove two new line characters with `.Text = Replace(.Text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, "")`
I also tried the following code but it fails to work either.

```
With Selection
    Do While InStr(1, .Text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        .Text = Replace(.Text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrlF)
    Loop
End With
```

I came up with another piece of code. I almost does the trick, ie. removes tabs,  both leading and trailing spaces, and more than two spaces. But it also removes *all* new line characters and I would like to remove only duplicated new line characters (i.e. more than one). Regex `\p{2,}` nor `\n` does not work here. It would be also great to remove empty lines.

```
Sub test()
    With Selection
        Dim RegEx As Object
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
        RegEx.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
        .Text = Trim(RegEx.Replace(.Text, " "))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub CleanUpPastedText()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Selection.Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      'Eliminate spaces & tabs before paragraph breaks.
      .Text = "[ ^s^t]{1,}^13"
      .Replacement.Text = "^p"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      'Replace single paragraph breaks with a space
      .Text = "([!^13])([^13])([!^13])"
      .Replacement.Text = "\1 \3"
      'Replace all double spaces with single spaces
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .Text = "[ ]{2,}"
      .Replacement.Text = " "
      'Delete hypens in hyphenated text formerly split across lines
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .Text = "([a-z])-[ ]{1,}([a-z])"
      .Replacement.Text = "\1\2"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      'Limit paragraph breaks to one per 'real' paragraph.
      .Text = "[^13]{1,}"
      .Replacement.Text = "^p"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    'Restore Screen Updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Edit**

Above code will work for 2007 and 2010.

For Office 16, you should use `^013` instead of `^13`

Comment: The code stops at first occurrence of `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll`

Comment: Are you selecting the text before executing? For word 2007 it is working fine. Which version you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am. I use Word 2016. Tomorrow I can check in on Word 2010, and probably on 2013.

Comment: That May be The Reason. Let Me Try 2016.

Comment: When thecode stops do you get an error message? What's it say?

Comment: It gives "Run-time error 5560: The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid."

Comment: @CindyMeister: Has anything changed after Word 2010 with regards to regular expression. I am successfully using this code in both 2007 and 2010.

Comment: @menteith It's possible your Windows system configuration uses a semicolon instead of a comma as the list separator. Does this work for the first pattern: "[ ^s^t]{1;}^13"

Comment: I use Windows 7 Pro EN x86. @CindyMeister It doesn't work.

Comment: @menteith. In the Windows control panel, in the Region and Language/Formats/Additional Settings check what's entered for "List separator". If it's something other than comma (,) or semicolon (;) try substituting that.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have semicolon.

Comment: @menteith It works for me like this in 2016: "[ ^s^t]{1;}^013" Notice the 013, I added the 0.

Comment: @CindyMeister I don't have acess to Word 2016 at the moment, but the changed code fails to work in Word 2010 PL in Windows 7 Enterprise PL x64. Tomorrow I will have acess to Word 2016 and I can check it.

Comment: @menteith: What did I just said in earlier comment? I am successfully using this code in both 2007 and 2010. Please read the comments before blindly commenting. for office 2010 and 2007 no need to change the code.

Comment: My mistake. I wanted to write that the code (either changed or not) fails to work on Word 2010.

Comment: It just works fine with my windows 7 pro. 64X and Office 2010 32X. Can you just tell me where in 2010 error is comming.

Comment: On Win 7 Ent. PL and Word 2010 Standard x64 the error is from the line: `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` (first one). I think I know what was wrong. If in all `.Text` like `"[ ^s^t]{1,}^13` you replace comma (,) with a semicolon (;) the macro works. I have found a suggestion to do so in [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1545817)

Comment: It was not even needed if you would have read the 9th comment, you would have got the answer. If anyone give their valuable comment to answer your question, you should have courtesy to read it.

Comment: Cindy wrote: 'Notice the 013, I added the 0'. There was no mentioned of semicolon, so I only changed the code to use 0.

Comment: see comment 9, where see wrote :It's possible your Windows system configuration uses a semicolon instead of a comma as the list separator. Does this work for the first pattern: "[ ^s^t]{1;}^13". If you are stupid enough not to find this comment then press ctrl+c then ctrl+f then ctrl+v and find this comment in this same page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to clean text. Let's consider the following text:

```
                John              Smith




John                    Anderson Smith
John      A. Smith
J.A. Smith






<below many new line character, some lines with spaces, tabs>
```

The code in the other answer makes:

```
      John Smith
John                    Anderson Smith John A. Smith J.A. Smith
```

This is obviously not correct. Here's my code:

```
With selection
        Dim RegEx As Object
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.Pattern = "[ \t]+"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, " ")
        RegEx.MultiLine = True
        RegEx.Pattern = "^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
        ' the following is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24049145/2657875
        RegEx.Pattern = "^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
End With
```

The code produces the following which is the expected result.

```
Jim Kane
John Andy Lemar
J. A. Smith
Jane Smith
```

Comment: There is no need of regex object here. Wildcard is already present in word find and replace to do what you are doing here.