# Merge Three Regexes into One (or Two)

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I would like to merge my three regexes which clean text (empty lines, leading and trailing spaces etc.) into, if possible, one regex, or if it is not possible - into two.

My first regex is [`[ \t]+`](https://regex101.com/r/nO6eB9/1). It does this sort of cleaning.

[image: first image]

My second regex is [`^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+`](https://regex101.com/r/nO6eB9/2) Not image included since it won't catch anything if the previous regex has not run.

The third regex is [`^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/nO6eB9/3). It does this sort of cleaning.

[image: second image]

**EDIT:** I have forgotten to mention that in each case I replace match with nothing `""`.

**EDIT 2:** I use the following code in Word:

```
With selection
        Dim RegEx As Object
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.MultiLine = True
        ' clean selection
        RegEx.Pattern = "[ \t]+"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, " ")
        RegEx.Pattern = "^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
        ' the following is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24049145/2657875
        RegEx.Pattern = "^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
End With
```

Comment: Do you replace with the same pattern? Also note that `\s` includes `\x0A`, you do not need to use `[\s\xA0]`, just `\s` is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi again. I have updated my first post.

Comment: So, it is impossible to use just one RegExp.Replace. Use two: 1) `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+|[ \t]+` to replace with `vbCr`, and 2) `^\s+|\s+$` to replace with nothing. If the last regex is not used with multiline option, consider just using `Trim()` instead and then you will just need the first, single regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect, as always. So, is it possible to merge these three regexes if each time they would be replaces with the same character (namely `""`)? If so, that would work for me.

Comment: Yes, it will work if you just use the `|` alternation operator.

Comment: So, have you tried [`^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+|[ \t]+|^\s+|\s+$`](https://regex101.com/r/zG8uZ5/1)? Looking at this expression, I think you can even shorten it to `[ \t]+|^\s+|\s+$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Have a look at my an example of a Word document that needs cleaning: [to be cleaned](http://i.imgur.com/5ywHC51.jpg) and the result with your regexes (each seems to work the same): [after cleaning](http://i.imgur.com/Ursf9aK.jpg). As you can see the result is different from that of my three regexes.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far for testing.

Comment: Do you mean the code I have been using so far?  If so, please see my first post. I have updated it.

Comment: Wiktor, I have mislead you. As you can see in the code in my first post, the match of first regex is replaced with `" "` not with `""`. Sorry for that. I should have been more attentive when asking for help.

Comment: You may try to merge last two regexps into `RegEx.Pattern = "^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)?)*|[ \t]+$"`.

Comment: Works great.Please submit your solution as an answer so that I can mark it adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last regexps can be merged as

```
RegEx.Pattern = "^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)?)*|[ \t]+$"
```

I do not think there can be a chance to merge all 3 in VBA since you are using two different replacement patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you want all your lines/spaces/tabs/white lines to be matched and removed, so you could merge the input strings. Well, that's easy and can be done if you do use the following regex in your replace program/script/command:

```
                 /([\s\t]{0,50}\r?\n)+|\s+/s
```

The regex should work well on windows as well as linux based files.

Answer (score 0):

Not pro but I use multiple regex one after another. If you are not familiar with below code than you should try.

```
Set regEx_ = new regExp
With regEx_
 .Global = True
 .MultiLine = True
 .IgnoreCase = True
 .Pattern = "Pattern 1"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "")
.Pattern = "Pattern 2"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "")
'and so on
End With
```

Comment: That's exacly what I use. But I would like to merge those regexes, not use what I have been using so far.

Comment: If you find answer please share it, as it will be also useful for users like me.

Comment: @menteith: so you can not do series of replacement in one go.